# Getting back contents of a div replaced by a new ajaxed div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have div with some content

```
    <div id="a">
      content
    </div>
```

i used jquery ajax to replace that div with another when it is clicked..

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'page.html',
      success:function(data){
      $('#a').replaceWith(data);
      }
     });
```

and i have a new div

```
    <div id="b">
      new content
    </div>
```

Now i want to add a back button in the new div to go back to the original div...
Is there any way to get back the content of the first div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Store it in a variable.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    success:function(data){
      var oldA = $('#a'); // oldA will still contain old data
      oldA.replaceWith(data);
    }
 });
```

Comment: How to access that variable and save it?

Comment: what do you mean by *save it*?

Comment: Like making it a constant

Comment: @hrishi, you can access oldA which will have the value. That is all I can tell